# How to enable and disable items in alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

My question is i dont want to select same option twice.
When it is clicked for 1st time it should be disable. Later when we choose another item, disabled item should be enabled. How can I achieve that?

```
public class AddDriverStateDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private static AddDriverStateDialog addDriverStateDialog;

    // Data references
    private int DRIVER_STATE = 0;
    private final String[] items = {"On Duty", "Off Duty", "Sleeper", "Driving","Yard Move","Personal Conveyance"};
    private ItemAdapter itemAdapter;
    // UI References
    private View view;
    private RadioRealButtonGroup radioButtonGroup;
    private EditText note,edittime;
    Calendar calendar;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public static AddDriverStateDialog newInstance(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        if (addDriverStateDialog == null) {
            addDriverStateDialog = new AddDriverStateDialog();
        }

        addDriverStateDialog.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        return addDriverStateDialog;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Initialise UI elements
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mainActivity).inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_driver_state, null);
        radioButtonGroup = (RadioRealButtonGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup_dialog_addDriverState_driverStates);
        note = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_dialog_addDriverState_note);
        //edittime= (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_dialog_addDriverState_time);
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        // UI Interaction listeners
        /* Driver State Selection Listener */
        radioButtonGroup.setOnClickedButtonListener(new RadioRealButtonGroup.OnClickedButtonListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClickedButton(RadioRealButton button, int position) {
                switch (button.getId()) {
                    case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_offDuty:
                        DRIVER_STATE = DriverState.STATE_OFFLINE;
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_onDuty:
                        DRIVER_STATE = DriverState.STATE_ONLINE;
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_sleeperBerth:
                        DRIVER_STATE = DriverState.STATE_SLEEPER;
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_driving:
                        DRIVER_STATE = DriverState.STATE_DRIVING;
                        break;
                    case  R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_yard_move:
                        DRIVER_STATE = DriverState.STATE_YARD_MOVE;
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioBtn_dialog_addDriverState_personal_conveyance:
                        DRIVER_STATE=DriverState.STATE_PERSONAL_CONVEYANCE;
                        break;
                }

            }

        });



    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity)
                .setTitle("Add Event")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setView(view)

                .setPositiveButton("Log Event", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        mainActivity.updateDashboard(DRIVER_STATE, note.getText().toString());
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .create();

    }
}
```

Comment: use bools. if option is clicked, set it to false. if that button is false, you disable it, else its enabled. easiest way

Answer (score -2):

Why not use a dialog with options like described [here](http://www.praveenboyalapalli.com/2015/05/display-alertdialog-with-multiple-options/)?